# ambiguous error using generics in rxjava to loop condition

Tags: java, loops, rx-java, rx-java2

I can't use takeUntil in rxjava because I receive this error:

`takeUntil(Predicate<? super T>) is ambiguous for the type (Flowable<T>)`

my code is like this:

```
public class Step {

  private Integer actualStep;
  private Integer nextStep;
  //getters and setters
}

public Interface<T> BusinessStep {

  Single<T> execute(T data);
}

public ComposedStep<T extends Step> implements BusinessStep<T> {
  private Map<Integer,BusinessStep<T>> steps = new HashMap<>();
  
  public void addStep(final Integer priority,
      final BusinessStep<T> businessStepValidator) {
    if (Objects.isNull(priority) || Objects.isNull(businessStepValidator)) {
      return;
    }
    validations.put(priority, businessStepValidator);
  }
   
   @override
   public Single<T> stepValidator(final T data) {

    return Single.just(data)
                 .flatMap(x -> {
                  Optional<WrapperBusinessStepValidator<T>> oBusinessStep = 
                                                        Optional.ofNullable(validations
                                                       .get(x.getNextStep()));
                  if(oBusinessStep.isPresent()) {
                    return oBusinessStep.get().stepValidator(x);
                  } else {
                    return Single.just(x);
                  }
                 })
                 .repeat()
                 .takeUntil(x -> x.getNextStep().equals(Integer.zero))
                 .lastElement()
                 .toSingle()
                 ;
                 

  }
}
```

in `steps` there are a map with implementations of BusinessStep to receive a child of Step and change `nextStep`.
I need to create a loop in order to execute several BusinessStep while `nextStep` is different to a condition.

The problem is that code isn't compile because the error that I mentioned in first part of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know if you want
`takeUntil(Predicate<? super T>)` or `takeUntil(Publisher<U>)`, because technically your lambda function matches both. Just explicitly cast it tell the compiler which you want:

```
      .takeUntil((Predicate<? super T>) x -> x.getNextStep().equals(Integer.zero))
```

Even this will remove the ambiguity (though I'm not 100% sure why, given that `equals` is already returning a `boolean`):

```
      .takeUntil(x -> (boolean) x.getNextStep().equals(Integer.zero))
```

Comment: In Java, you don't have to use the returned value of an expression, i.e., `x.getNextStep().equals(Integer.zero);` would be just fine as statement. In lambda, you omit the `;` so the compiler can't say you intended to ignore the returned value, thus pick `Publisher` or meant to use the returned value, thus pick `Predicate`. `boolean` cast would not make sense as part of the statement hence the use disambiguates.